# php mail subject not send

Tags: php

i'm trying to send email with php and it works good but only the message i receive has issue, subject don't work. Can anybody find the problem?

```
  <?php
        $to = "me@email.com";
        $name = $_REQUEST['name'];
        $headers = "From: $from";
        $subject = "You have a message from $name.";
        $fields = array();
        $fields{"email"} = "email";
        $fields{"message"} = "message";
        $body = "Message:\n\n"; foreach($fields as $a => $b){   $body .= sprintf("%20s: %s\n",$b,$_REQUEST[$a]); }
        $send = mail($to, $body, $headers, $subject);
    ?>
```

Comment: This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing `$send` order as the following;

```
 $send = mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
```

**Update**: 
Thanks to David for pointing out, add the variable `$from` to your php so the sender's email will be included in the `$headers` too:

```
<?php
        $to = "me@email.com";
        $from = $_REQUEST['from'];
        $name = $_REQUEST['name'];
        $headers = "From: $from";
        $subject = "You have a message from $name.";
        $fields = array();
        $fields{"email"} = "email";
        $fields{"message"} = "message";
        $body = "Message:\n\n"; foreach($fields as $a => $b){   $body .= sprintf("%20s: %s\n",$b,$_REQUEST[$a]); }
        $send = mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
    ?>
```

Comment: Also the variable $from is never set but is used on line 4.

Comment: @David Nice catch! Just added that to the answer.

Comment: you have to still fix the `mail` function in the "Update" section.

Comment: @David Just fixed it! Thanks!